# PHP Form Mailer on an SSL Site

Tags: php, forms, ssl, mailer

I'm having a hard time finding a solution to a problem that should have a very simple solution.

I created a PHP form mailer that worked on my customer's site.  He then decided to get an SSL certificate, and since then, the form mailer doesn't work.  I don't get any errors at all.  Everything appears to have been sent, but I haven't received any emails from the form.

I then created a nonsense form with one field and a very basic PHP form mailer to see if I can troubleshoot the problem, but even this basic code does not work.

Does the mail() function not work with SSL? I'm thinking I'm missing something relevant somewhere.  This is the first time I've worked with SSL, but I'm more than capable of creating the code if only I can get some direction, which is the reason for this post.  Any guidance, direction, or critique will be very appreciated.

---MY NONSENSE FORM USED FOR TESTING---

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="testFormsub.php">
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---MY BASIC PHP FORM MAILER---

```
<?php
$test = $_POST['text1'];
$to="email@email.com";
$subject="Thank you for registering.";
$header="From: TEST EMAIL <email@email.com>";
$message="PLEASE WORK...$test \r\n";
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
?>
```

Comment: I solved this one.  For reference, I searched (and searched and searched) and found phpmailer.  I downloaded and installed it, changed some of the settings and I was done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two separate pages for mailing as in a form page and results page?

If so, are you using SSL for both pages?

if not, the problem likely lies in the fact that your sendmail page uses SSL and your testFormsub.php is not using SSL.